# No height using Chris Coyier full width hack

Tags: css, height, width

I'm using Chris Coyier's full width hack on a site I am building, but stumped on how I can get the div to have the height of whatever it is containing.

Usually I would achieve this by adding overflow:auto to the container, but if I do that it breaks the hack. Is it possible to achieve a height and still use this hack?

You can see my problem here: http://beta.revival.tv/

Here is my CSS:

```
#content-wrap:before, #content-wrap:after {content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 9999px;}

#content-wrap:before {right: 100%;}

#content-wrap:after {left: 100%;}

#content-wrap, #content-wrap:before, #content-wrap:after {background:#666;}

#content-wrap {
position: relative;
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:25px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another div to contain the content inside of the #content-wrap div and then apply overflow: auto; and width: 100%; to it

```
<div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>

#content { 
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I don't know your html, but if the problem is caused by floating elements inside of the div, you may also want to try using display: inline-block; instead